# OSX Anaconda default python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, anaconda, bash

I have anaconda distribution installed on my macbook to my local home directory `/Users/simon/anaconda`

When I open up iterm and type `python` I see the default OSX install of python. I saw this thread here and implemented the fix mentioned: [Mac using default Python despite Anaconda install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773432/mac-using-default-python-despite-anaconda-install)

My `.bash_profile` currently looks like this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

A few strange things happen:

1. When I type `python` I still see the OSX python despite having changed my `.bash_profile`
2. If I `source /Users/simon/.bash_profile` this actually fixes the problem. Using `python` now brings up anaconda's python
3. When I quit iterm or restart my computer and try to load python again, it goes back to the OSX version. `.bash_profile` remains unchanged.

When I try all of the above using terminal everything works fine. The issues described above appear to be specific to iterm2 and I'm not sure why

How do I get my system to use anacondas python instead of the OSX version?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $HOME` ?

Comment: `/Users/simon` for both iterm and terminal

Comment: By any chances, do you have any `dotfile` installed ? could you `echo $PATH` before and after sourcing the `.bash_profile` ?

Comment: I do have a number of dotfiles (emacs, zsh etc). Before: `/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` and after: `/Users/simon/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: OK it turns out I was exporting a different PATH in my .zshrc file. I changed it to what was in my bash profile and it all works now...Are there any issues with exporting PATH in multiple places like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `$PATH` is redefined somewhere else in your configuration. This usually doesn't cause issue if you know in which order they are loaded and keep track of what's going on.

I recommend a bit of [reading](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) to understand more the load order.