# Orekit killing python3 on M2 (Mac) via Anaconda

Tags: python, package, conda, zsh

I know that Anaconda has an easy install command for Orekit, but something's not working out. It seems this is par for the course based on [this Orekit discussion](https://forum.orekit.org/t/orekit-python-wrapper-on-mac-m2/2571/4). Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Download / install Anaconda via [the installer](https://www.anaconda.com/download#macos) using the "Download for Mac (M1/M2) option. Wait for completion.
2. Edit the `~/.zshrc` file using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773432/mac-using-default-python-despite-anaconda-install#:%7E:text=Update%20for%20all,So%20instead%20do%3A) to point `python3` command to the Anaconda distribution.
3. Validate Conda being opened when `python3` is executed in terminal:

   `>>> python3`

   `Python 3.11.0 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jan 14 2023, 12:25:12) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin`
4. Install Orekit using the link from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/orekit) (conda install -c conda-forge orekit). Wait to complete.
5. Re-run Anaconda via the terminal, and import Orekit (`import orekit`)

When I do so, the following text is returned:

```
>>> import orekit
    zsh: killed python3
```

I'm confused, to say the least. Any suggestions are appreciated, considering this seems like a pretty straight-forward task. Per requests from the comments...

Here is the return from `conda info`:

```
(python3p8) apung@MacBookPro-MTXQM1Y6PM ~ % conda info 

     active environment : python3p8
    active env location : /Users/apung/anaconda3/envs/python3p8
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/apung/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/apung/.condarc
          conda version : 23.5.2
    conda-build version : 3.25.0
         python version : 3.11.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=arm64
                          __osx=13.4.1=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /Users/apung/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/apung/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/apung/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/apung/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/apung/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/apung/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/23.5.2 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.11.3 Darwin/22.5.0 OSX/13.4.1
                UID:GID : 502:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

and here is the return from `conda list`:

```
(python3p8) apung@MacBookPro-MTXQM1Y6PM ~ % conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/apung/anaconda3/envs/python3p8:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
bzip2                     1.0.8                h3422bc3_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.5.7             hf0a4a13_0    conda-forge
libcxx                    16.0.6               h4653b0c_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hca03da5_0  
libsqlite                 3.42.0               hb31c410_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h53f4e23_5    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h313beb8_0  
openjdk                   8.0.332              he4db4b2_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                h53f4e23_1    conda-forge
orekit                    11.3.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.1.2           py38hca03da5_0  
python                    3.8.17          h3ba56d0_0_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      3_cp38    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0  
setuptools                67.8.0           py38hca03da5_0  
sqlite                    3.41.2               h80987f9_0  
tk                        8.6.12               hb8d0fd4_0  
wheel                     0.38.4           py38hca03da5_0  
xz                        5.4.2                h80987f9_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h53f4e23_5    conda-forge
```

Comment: Please add output of `conda info` to the question body. Please show `conda list` for the environment - we need to see whether **osx-64** or **osx-arm64** packages are being installed. BTW, Users who intend to use Conda Forge packages are usually better off starting from Mambaforge or another Miniforge variant, rather than Anaconda/Miniconda.

Comment: Thanks, @merv. I've added this information per your request.

Comment: Thanks. Could you create a new environment that only uses Conda Forge? Something like: `conda create -n foo -c conda-forge orekit python=3.8` should work. We should rule out that [channel mixing](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels) isn't the issue.

Comment: @merv, I created the new environment using your command, then switched to the new environment (`conda activate foo`). Within the `foo` environment, I opened `python3`, which opened `Python 3.8.17 | packaged by conda-forge`. Within Python, I ran `import orekit`, which gave me the same output as last time: `zsh: killed     python3`